# Can i use two different flexDirection in a view?

Tags: react-native, flexbox

i want a View with 3 button like this:

[image]

So i have this code:

```
<View>
  <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'flex-end' }}>
    <CircleButton>
    </CircleButton>
  </View>
  <View style={{ margin: 16, alignItems: 'flex-end', flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
    <Button>
      Annulla
    </Button>
    <Button>
      Conferma
    </Button>
  </View>
</View>
```

But the result is this:

[image]

How can i place the view with two different flexDirection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add empty space between your two `View` elements.

edit: At first I offered to add en empty `View` with `flex-grow: 1` between the two views, but I think the following is more elegant.

Taking the second example [in the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html), I'd assume this would do the trick - can you try?

```
<View style={{
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'space-between'
  }}>
  <View style={{ alignSelf: 'flex-end' }}>
    <CircleButton>
    </CircleButton>
  </View>
  <View style={{ margin: 16, width: '100%', flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
    <Button>
      Annulla
    </Button>
    <Button>
      Conferma
    </Button>
  </View>
</View>
```

Overall, it looks like you didn't grasp Flexbox properly yet. I highly recommend [this guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to wrap your head around it.